# C++ Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, адрес

```
#include <iostream>

class Character
{
private:
    short x = -1;
    short y = -1;
};


class Luchnik : public Character
{
public:
    Luchnik(short x, short y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
private:
    short x = 0;
    short y = 0;
};


int main() {
    Luchnik *l = new Luchnik(1, 2);
    Character a();
    &a = l;

    delete l;
    return 0;
}
```

visual stuido пишет Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значение.

вот скрин

[image: "]

**Update**

а можно в конструкторе Luchnik получить указатель вектора и менять vector[x][y] объект на Luchnil

я написал так, но не работает, я что-то плохо понимаю указатели и классы

```
Luchnik(short x, short y, std::vector<std::vector<Character>> map) {
   this->x = x;
   this->y = y;
   Character* pm = &(map[x][y]);
   pm = *this;
}
```

```
int main() { 
    std::vector<std::vector<Character>> board = new std::vector<std::vector<Character>>(3, std::vector<Character>(4));
    Luchnik l(1, 2, *board);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все верно, ведь присвоить что-то **адресу** объекта невозможно. Это все равно, что присвоить переменную значению:

```
int i = 5;
2 = i;
```

Здесь у вас возражений нет, что такое присваивание недопустимо?

Но в любом случае учтите, что

```
Character a();
```

представляет собой *объявление функции* без аргументов, возвращающей значение типа `Character`.

Объявление объекта `a` типа `Character` должно иметь иной вид:

```
Character a;
```

или

```
Character a{};
```

Подсказать, как именно исправить ваш код, можно будет только после того, как вы поясните, что вы хотите сделать, что этот код должен, по-вашему, делать.

**Update**

Если я верно понял вашу задачу, то вам надо создать вектор *указателей* `vector<Character*>`; тогда вы сможете присваивать указатель на потомка:

```
vector<Character*> vc;
......
vc[i] = new Luchnik(1, 2);
```

С `vector<Character>` вы не сможете работать из-за *срезки*, а вектор ссылок создается сложно, через прокси-класс `reference_wrapper`, мне кажется, вам с этим связываться не стоит. Через указатели проще.

**Update 2** (мы этот вопрос вообще когда-то закроем? :))

Вероятно, вы хотите следующее:

```
Luchnik(short x, short y, std::vector<std::vector<Character*>>& map)
    :x(x),y(y)
{
    map[x][y] = this;
}
```

Еще раз: работать с `std::vector<std::vector<Character>>` не получится из-за [срезки](https://ravesli.com/urok-170-obrezka-obektov/).

Comment: Я пишу что-то вроде шахмат, и мне нужно менять один элемент из  масива/вектора<Character> на Luchnik. я создал класс Character чтобы сделать его классом родителя отсталых персонажей чтобы мог в масива/вектора<Character> менять из Character на Luchnik или на другие персонажи.

извини за ошибки я не руский, если что то непонятно могу объяснить еше.

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: а можно в конструкторе Luchnik получить указатель вектора и менять vector[x][y] объект на Luchnil?

как показал на вопросе выше.

Comment: Ну, можно и это, но не так, как вы пишете. См. очередное обновление ответа...

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь изменить у переменной адрес по которому она лежит. С++ не позволяет такое сделать. Для того чтобы сослатся на существующий объект необходимо использоват указатели или ссылки.

В случае указателей код будет таким:

```
Character* a = l;
```

И такой для ссылки:

```
Character& a = *l;
```